# how to catch every exception of main exe from a dll & exceptions from dll itself

Tags: c++, exception, code-injection, shellcode, dll-injection

how can i catch any exception of main exe from my injected dll and of the dll itself? Is something i can hook to get any exception?
Since now i tried catch all exceptions from my dll with this way

```
try
{
    MainScriptFuntion();
}
catch (...)
{
    log("error");
}
```

this doesn't catch any exception of the dll like out of range (i tried for string,vector,dictionary) etc...
How can i fix this problem? And how can i catch exceptions of main exe code?

**1st EDIT**:
here is an example. I use a std::map to  translate a text.

```
const inline std::wstring& GetWord(const std::wstring& key)
    {
        try {
            std::wstring& word(dict.at(key));
            return word;
        }
        catch (...) {}

        return key;
    }
```

the `std::map::at` function throw an exception if the key not found in map.
For more information take a look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

If create a exe program and use this function, i see it catch the exception so it return the key (if not found). However if use this function within a DLL and inject the dll in a running process, then it crash-close whole application because it cannot catch the exception

**2nd EDIT**: i notice that if inject DLL with native injection method i can handle exceptions, but if inject with manual map method i cannot. So maybe is issue of injector? I do everything that need to manually map the dll correctly:

- resolving relocations
- resolving imports
- map sections to its VA
- call my DllMain

need to do something more or it isn't problem of injector?

Comment: Dereferencing a `nullptr` doesn't usually throw an exception. It it just Undefiend Behavior and will typically cause a crash, but anything could happen. Not all errors are exceptions in C++. Most of the time, breaking a C++ rule is just not allowed, it is your responsibility to make sure you always follow the language's requirements and there is usually no way to recover if you do.

Comment: *Your* code that throws a C++ exception, shrouded within a proper `try-catch` within *your* function to prevent said-same from permeating to the thread-activation layer, should work. If you're talking about handling [*structured exceptions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling), that's something different (and usually ends up going badly in the end anyway; at best, the general reason for doing this is to get to a (hopefully) safe point of saving data, reaping crash conditions, and semi-gracefully terminating the process).

Comment: These are not c++ exceptions. If you have corrupted memory or access violation there is not much to do. You may try to call some platform-dependent function to create dump or start another process to show an error. Other actions will most likely fail.

Comment: Putting aside the issues of not all problems being nice C++ exceptions, you might be able to catch whatever uncaught things happen to occur by having your DLL use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setunhandledexceptionfilter Though whether you can actually do anything useful and reliable in the unhandledexceptionfilter depends on what you want to do. And whether you could reasonably get useful information from the caught exception is another challenge.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i deleted that example, but from that i know if use delete operator to delete an object and try access a variable that was inside this class object, then will throw a Access Violation exception

Comment: @ACresearcher That access violation is *not guaranteed*, but even so, an access violation is simply not a C++ exception, it is an OS exception, so you can't catch it with `catch(...)` (unless the compiler's underlying error handling mechanism catches OS exceptions and converts them into C++ exceptions - most do not!)

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay it's good to know, thanks. I just want catch every exception i can so i can avoid crashes when this is possible to do

Comment: The is no `Access violation` in **standard C++**. If your application is compiled for .NET (C++/CLI with `/clr` option) but not your DLL, then obviously the DLL knows nothing about managed exceptions. Also unless you write code for SEH exceptions, **Win32 exceptions will not be handled**. In general, for non-critical applications, you probably simply want to ignore them and let the application crash. Also obvious is the fact that **you do not want to use** `at` if it is expected that an item might not exist. **Instead, use** `find` and check the returned iterator.

Comment: "*I just want catch every exception i can so i can avoid crashes when this is possible to do* - and that is where many beginners get themselves into trouble. By the time a crash occurs, the damage has already been done, the state of the program is unstable. Recovery *may* be possible, but unlikely, so why attempt to catch the error at all? There is little you will be able to *do* with it (except maybe to just log it). The reasonable solution would be to just let it crash, restart the program, and fix the crashing code. Catching an exception just to discard it is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Phil1970 i don't use .NET or CLI, i created an empty DLL project and i coded everything

Comment: @RemyLebeau i think i'm not beginner anymore, i code over 4 years in c++. The DLL i that i code right now using direct2D library to draw my GUI. So my idea was in case that something unexpected happend not crash, release and re-init the GUI and try again 1-2 times, if keep failing then log the error and exit. Also i would like to catch exceptions of the main program because i use some shared textures&objects for rendering and sometimes need to know if main program crashed by the dll or if was other problem, so in this case i need log the errors to fix the bugs

Comment: (1) Is your executable compiler with same compiler and run-time as the DLL? If not, then you might have incompatibilities related to exception handling. (2) Is `dict` object in the same DLL (or EXE) as the function? (3) Is the function called from the same DLL. (4) Have you tried to use a non-inline function instead. **There is surely a reason for the observed behavior**. Information on compiler, options, run-time, injection and more would be useful as your code is perfectly good if everything (caller, called, exception, dictionary object...) is in the same EXE or DLL as you already know.

Comment: @Phil1970 (1) i only know that the EXE created with c++, i make the DLL with c++ too, (2) dict object is in the same class as the function i posted, this class is inside the DLL, (3) yes, (4) yes i tried it

Comment: I think that more need to be done but that information is probably not officially documented. When using regular DLLs, LoadLibrary and similar, the compiler will do any initialization required to make things works. Injection essentially bypass that. Maybe you could try to add structured error handling to see if it help. Otherwise, maybe the only sensible solution is to turn off exception and write code accordingly (more or less C code)

Answer (score 1):

A C++ exception is caught by the enclosing `try { } catch` block. Your **injected** DLL does not *have* an enclosing `try { } catch` block surrounding it. It was injected into an EXE that is unaware of the DLL.

Furthermore, the C++ runtime that has to handle exceptions is also not designed with DLL injection in mind. It might just work inside the DLL, but even that is not guaranteed. DLL injection is not something that normal programs do.

Things get **really** messy if the C++ runtime for your DLL is itself in another DLL, and the main EXE happens to use a DLL with the same name. You now get version conflicts etcetera.

Comment: I use manual mapping injection method, i don't use LoadLibrary to inject it, so the main program doesn't know the name of my dll and there is no way to cause conflicts. So try{} catch{} is always useless for injected DLLs? Then can i hook the main loop function of the main EXE and add a try{} catch {} block there? Or this will not work?

Comment: @ACresearcher: How do you know there's a "main loop funcion"? Or even that the EXE is compiled with the same CC++ compiler?

Comment: i hook a function of the EXE (with minhook lib) to run my DLL code. This function called by the EXE in loop. When i inject the DLL (1) i create a new thread, (2) i do some signature scans, (3) i create some hooks (this looped funtion, get window messages-inputs, EXE's D3D rendering hook), (4) i switch thread to fiber when the main looped funtion get called by EXE, (5) switch fiber to thread when finish my DLL loop funtion and wait until hook get called again... I only know that EXE coded with c++, i don't know which version or IDE used